# zipoutputstream adding root drive path too before the folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip, compression

I am creating a zip file using zioutpoustream but when i open zip file it shows the root path first like D:LocalDisk and not the folder which was zipped.
This is my code for creating zip

```
public void StartZip(string directory, string zipfile_path)
{
    // the directory you need to zip
    DirectoryInfo Dictiontory = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    //to get sub directories
    DirectoryInfo[] Dir = Dictiontory.GetDirectories();
    string[] filenames;
    // path which the zip file built in
    ZipOutputStream s = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(zipfile_path));
    foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in Dir)
    {
        filenames = Directory.GetFiles(directory+"/"+folder);
        foreach (string filename in filenames)
        {
            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
            s.PutNextEntry(entry);
            s.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
    s.SetLevel(5);
    s.Finish();
    s.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if anyone facing the same issue:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(directory, zipfile_path);
```